# Is there a log for Identification of upper CPU/Memory usage process

Tags: azure, memory-management, cpu-usage, azure-log-analytics

I am using Azure Monitor (Log analytics) to identification the upper CPU/ Memory usage process.

There is a new Azure Virtual Machine which runs Windows 2012R2, I had installed the Log Analytics agent to the VM and I can get some data from the VM.

I try to use some code to get the top 5 CPU usage process, but I just got the VM name instead of processes.

> `Perf | where CounterName == "% Processor Time"` 
>   `|top 5 by CounterValue nulls first`

I expect the output of the upper CPU/ Memory usage process name.

Comment: what do you mean that "but I just got the VM name instead of processes."? as per your query code, it would return all the data.

Comment: @IvanYang But I can't see the process name like Google Chrome, system or window updates.......

Comment: can you please check if the process name is in InstanceName?

Comment: can you see the process name in InstanceName column?

Comment: @IvanYang no, the InstanceName is "_Total".

Comment: Please check if this is what you are looking for. https://www.systemcenterautomation.com/2018/07/cpu-processes-azure-log-analytics/ , https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukhybridcloud/2017/12/13/azure-log-analytics-finding-cpus-with-perf-counters/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AW1cdnz3ac